# User’s activity history in iPhone

Tags: iphone, android-activity

I want to make an app, wherein I have access to the following

- Logs: call log, message log, app usage log, media log, ...
- Logging data per activity: ex) call log: call direction, phone number, call
  duration, location, ...
- Privacy policy (logging policy, using policy of the log data, user
  consent policy, ...)

Are there any APIs available to achieve above mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no public available API's that will allow you to access this information.